# Spring Batch Performance Testing

Tags: java, spring, parallel-processing, spring-batch, performance-testing

We have written a batch processing foundation framework on top of the Spring Batch Chunk Partitioning Architecture. (Master - Slave Parallel Processing Model) [1]

Now I want to test and visualize how the performance of batch jobs running through the batch framework varies based on the size of the batch vs the number of slaves (grid size) with analysis on how Throttle-limit parameter should be fine tuned. This is with purpose of understanding the optimal level of parallel processing a batch with minimum time using the batch framework.

I have not found an effective mechanism to achieve this? Any solutions or paradigms to build my pathway?

[1] http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/scalability.html

Answer (score 0):

I have had success using http://jmeter.apache.org/ to measure and visualize performance of Java applications.  You may be able to apply it here as well.  You could build a test plan that launched a shell script.  The shell script would start a CommandLineJobRunner to launch your job.  I don't think Jmeter would be able to tell you much more than total duration.

Another option would be to use JConsole, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html.